# Pop!_OS stuck BEFORE login

Tags: boot, pop-os, login-manager

I tried to reboot my laptop, running Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS, but I'm now facing a gray screen, the same gray than the login screen but without the possibility to login
I can't even open a tty, it just shows a black screen with a fixed blank underscore and I can't type anything

I didn't do anything unusual, I just added a crontab to start polybar on boot and un-did that in recovery mode

The system76 troubleshooting only lists the case where the gray screen appears after login, but I can't even login

I still followed the guide, updated everything, reinstalled everything related to the graphical output (which shouldn't be the problem since even the tty doesn't start) including the Nvidia drivers

I'm thus quite out of options, any  ideas?

Comment: Hi. Have you been able to resolve this? I have the same problem after update. Can see just black (dark grey?) screen and a single underscore. I am not even able to boot using a live usb

Comment: Hi, I switched to arch in the meantime and don't really remember how this issue turned out. But you could start by looking at the logs in recovery mode to look for any error. Maybe you could also ask a whole new question as you are able to try solutions unlike me, in which case I would delete this one. I would then happily try to help you

Comment: I was not able to boot into recovery mode and not even to other OS using Live USB, so ended up bringing PC to the repair shop. This looked possibly like some kind of BIOS issue. Thanks for the quick reply anyway.